# Error while reading csv file and returning dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

My below code does no work. Is there a better way to filter by column?

```
import pandas as pd     # To handle data

file=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Ankit\\Downloads\\file.csv",index_col=0)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweet.text for tweet in file], columns=['tweet'])
print(df)
```

Comment: What's the actual error? It's hard to work out what's wrong if we don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Are we supposed to do a vulcan mind meld over the internet to guess the error? Please edit your question and include the error and the raw data

Comment: Also why read the entire df, and then make a new df just of the tweet column? You can just read the tweet column: `df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Ankit\\Downloads\\file.csv",usecols=['text'], index_col=0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file` is *already* a dataframe. To filter for specific column(s), you don't need to create a new dataframe and extract data from `file`.

Instead, you can simply use your existing `pd.DataFrame` object and use standard `[]` indexing. Assuming you have a "tweet" column named as such:

```
file = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Ankit\\Downloads\\file.csv", index_col=0)
file_tweet = file[['tweet']]
```

Or, if you *only* ever need the one column, specify this when you read the file:

```
file = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Ankit\\Downloads\\file.csv",
                   index_col=0, use_cols=['tweet'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this,

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Ankit\\Downloads\\file.csv')
```

pd.read_csv will read the csv file and return it in dataframe.

Comment: Fine, you can see every column by dataframe = file[['columns_name']]